# Whats next after adding stripe ? I want to charge for a pro version, and give paid users extra features

Tags: express, stripe-payments

I am using express and mongodb.

I have succesfully added stripe, and i can make a test payment succesfully, i followed this tutorial: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/express

So, my question is, what would be the steps to take, so that when a user pays, he gets a flag of "pro user" and then he can accces certain features.

what is normally the process here? are there any tuts or guidelines i can check ? thx!

Comment: Its not about stripe, you need to add the features for the paid users. Consider i have an option to show feature listing in my application which can be accessed only by paid users. If this case, you can make a flag in db for paid users when they completed there payment. Only those users can access the page others will shown a message like "Subscribe to access the page". This is the simple example to different paid and normal user functionality

Comment: Ok.. makes sense... if you add this as answer ill accept it...thx!

Comment: Sure will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not about stripe, you need to add the features for the paid users. Consider i have an option to show feature listing in my application which can be accessed only by paid users. If this case, you can make a flag in db for paid users when they completed there payment. Only those users can access the page others will shown a message like "Subscribe to access the page". This is the simple example to different paid and normal user functionality